# Should I say little daughter or younger daughter?

Tags: comparative-degree

I have 2 daughters, they are 5 years old & 10 years old.

In some conversation, I need to mention my daughter with 5 years old.

Should I say littler daughter ? (I doubt it)

Or should I say younger daughter? it looks like "young" would refer to an adult?

Comment: 'Little' is informal and childish; 'younger' or 'small' are more standard.

Comment: _Young_ certainly doesn't have to refer to an adult; anyone is 'younger' if they are not as old as another person who has been mentioned. The ten-year-old might well refer to the other one as 'my little sister', especially as there is a five-year age difference between them.

Comment: "Little sister" & "Big sister" are common phrases (but have a childlike tone to them). "Little daughter" is not idiomatic, though.

Answer (score 1):

two daughters: My **younger** daughter versus My **older** daughter.

young is not just about adults.

younger and older are used as comparatives for ages. One daughter is younger than the other. One is older than the other.

two brothers:
This is my older brother.
This is my younger brother.

This brother is older than that brother. etc.